# Anyway a script can sort by word priority?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there anyway for a script such as the following to sort by word priority instead of alphabetically.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var xCol = 1;
  var yCol = 2;
  var tableRange = "A2:M100";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  dataRange.sort([
    {column: xCol, ascending: true},
    {column: yCol, ascending: true},
  ]);
}
```

Basically I need column 1 to remain sorting in alphabetical order, but column 2 sort in order by words. Sort of like

```
Charlie Egg
Echo    Rift
Alpha   Wood
Delta   Frog
Bravo   Egg
```

Becomes the following because column 1 is sorted alphabetically and column 2 is sorted by a word priority: Wood > Egg > Frog > Rift

```
Alpha   Wood
Bravo   Egg
Charlie Egg
Delta   Frog
Echo    Rift
```

Comment: Are you looking to sort both the columns alphabetically? Could you edit the question to include sample data before sorting and after sorting.

Comment: @AneesHameed Hopefully I have made my question more clear

Comment: I think you'll need to load the values into GAS, sort them and write them back, there it's trivial to implement if you have a list somewhere.